# Program/script/browser add on that automatically hits ok to message boxes

Tags: script, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions

There are websites that I use that have message boxes that pop up from time to time.  Is there a program/script/add-on I could get that would hit them automatically?

Yes, I am aware of dangerous message boxes that could pop up, I would only use this tool when I'm using the websites, otherwise, it would be off.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah one can use a program like that to automatically check web email (though it's not that secure to use it for that).  A program that can type text hit ENTER e.t.c. Or click OK in a message box by hitting tab to give OK focus and hitting Space to push the button. Or I suppose to enter your Address automatically (first line, tab, second line e.t.c.)

AutoIt is one.  Autohotkey is another.

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/AutoIt.shtml

http://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/

Comment: in addition, it's possible that Typeitin by wavget, would do it but I haven't tried it for that.